# A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. Asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a page which gives me this error in Firefox:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. 
>   You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script
>   will complete.

This is my jquery code:

```
 function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
             var imgDisplay = $get("imageEmployeeTemp");
             var img = new Image();
             img.onload = function () {
             imgDisplay.style.cssText = "height:100px;width:100px";
             imgDisplay.src = img.src;
             };
             img.src = "/Resources/Images/Employee/" + args.get_fileName();
         }

         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#TxBx_BasicSalary').focusout(function () {

                var EmployeeId = $('#Hid_EmpID').val();
                if (EmployeeId == 0) {
                    return;
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '/WebService/IncDedWebService.asmx/GetInceDed',
                    data: '{ "id": "' + EmployeeId + '" }',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                  var data = $.parseJSON(data.d)
                  var TotalIncentives = data["TotalIncentives"];
                  var TotalDeduction = data["TotalDeduction"];
                  var BasicSalary = $("#TxBx_BasicSalary").val();
                  var GrossSalary = parseInt(BasicSalary) + parseInt(TotalIncentives)
                   $('#Ltrl_GSalary').html(GrossSalary);
                   $('#Hid_GSalary').val(GrossSalary);  
                  $('#Ltrl_NetSalary').html(GrossSalary - parseInt(TotalDeduction));
                   $('#Hid_NetSalary').val(GrossSalary - parseInt(TotalDeduction));
                 },
                     error: function () { alert("error"); }
                 });
            });
             var id = "#<%= Rtb_PayMode.ClientID %>";
             var bool = false;
             $(id).click(function () {
                HideShowRows();
                 bool = true;
             });

             if (!bool) {
                 HideShowRows();
             }
             function HideShowRows() {
                var BankInfo = $('#BankInfo');
                 var BankAccount = $('#BankAccount');
                 if ($('#<%= Rtb_PayMode.ClientID %> input:checked').val() == '1') {
                     BankInfo.hide();
                     BankAccount.hide();
                }
                else {
                     BankInfo.show();
                     BankAccount.show();
                 }
             }
         });
```

Please help me what to do.

Comment: Have you tried debugging step by step to find where is freezing?

Comment: can you please tell me at which line debugger throws that error?

Comment: Just a fluke, can't it be that focusout is making multiple ajax calls due to which script reaches unresponsive sort of state. Try commenting out focusOut function once and see if it still hangs on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a flag to stop multiple simultaneous ajax requests:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var inProgress = false;
       $('#TxBx_BasicSalary').focusout(function () {

          if(!inProgress){
            inProgress = true;
            var EmployeeId = $('#Hid_EmpID').val();
            if (EmployeeId == 0) {
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '/WebService/IncDedWebService.asmx/GetInceDed',
                data: '{ "id": "' + EmployeeId + '" }',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                  inProgress = false;
                  var data = $.parseJSON(data.d)
                  var TotalIncentives = data["TotalIncentives"];
                  var TotalDeduction = data["TotalDeduction"];
                  var BasicSalary = $("#TxBx_BasicSalary").val();
                  var GrossSalary = parseInt(BasicSalary) + parseInt(TotalIncentives)
                  $('#Ltrl_GSalary').html(GrossSalary);
                  $('#Hid_GSalary').val(GrossSalary);  
                  $('#Ltrl_NetSalary').html(GrossSalary - parseInt(TotalDeduction));
                  $('#Hid_NetSalary').val(GrossSalary - parseInt(TotalDeduction));
             },
                 error: function () { alert("error"); }
             });
           }
      });
```

Comment: Or even better, set inProgress to equal an object containing the time of the latest request and a counter for how many ongoing requests there are. Each time focusout is called, that counter would be checked to be less than 4 (your browser can easily handle that) and run the rest of the code if it is (adding 1 to the counter). It would also store the time for that specific request in a local variable. Then when it's complete, both error and success callbacks would subtract 1 from the counter and the success callback would only run if its local time matches the time of the latest request.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem using ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload.
there is a workaround with css;

-apply `CssClass="asyncupload"` in your AsyncFileUpload,

-add class `.asyncupload input { width:100%!important; }` to your css file.